# Get partial string from string

Tags: c#

I have the following string:

```
This isMyTest testing
```

I want to get isMyTest as a result. I only have two first characters available("is"). The rest of the word can vary.

Basically, I need to select a first word delimeted by spaces which starts with chk.

I've started with the following:

```
if (text.contains(" is"))
{
text.LastIndexOf(" is"); //Should give me index.
}
```

now  I cannot find the right bound of the word since I need to match on something like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y.aspx) to get the index of the next space:

```
int startPosition = text.LastIndexOf(" is");
if (startPosition != -1)
{
    int endPosition = text.IndexOf(' ', startPosition + 1); // Find next space
    if (endPosition == -1)
       endPosition = text.Length - 1; // Select end if this is the last word?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions:

```
    string pattern = @"\bis";
    string input = "This isMyTest testing";
    return Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a regex match? Generally if you are searching for a pattern in a string (ie starting with a space followed by some other character) regex are perfectly suited to this. Regex statements really only fall apart in contextually sensitive areas (such as HTML) but are perfect for a regular string search.

```
// First we see the input string.
string input = "/content/alternate-1.aspx";

// Here we call Regex.Match.
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"[ ]is[A-z0-9]*",     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Here we check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
{
    // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```